# When page is loaded automatically all the input controls in page should be hidden using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

Am trying to hide and unhide input controls based on option button selection. It is working fine only when i select option button but i require when page is loaded some all the input control buttons has to be hidden and based on selection only it has to display respective input controls.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<div id="Radio" class="leaf">
    <fieldset class="control select multiple" title="">
        <legend>Select Input Criteria</legend>
        <ul class="list inputSet sizable">                <li>
                <div class="control radio">
                    <input checked="checked" class="" id="Radio1" type="radio" name="Radio_option" value="~NOTHING~">
                    <label class="wrap" for="Radio1" title="">
                        ---&nbsp;
                    </label>
                </div>
            </li>
                            <li>
                <div class="control radio">
                    <input class="" id="Radio2" type="radio" name="Radio_option" value="Enter by Account Number">
                    <label class="wrap" for="Radio2" title="">
                        Enter by Account Number&nbsp;
                    </label>
                </div>
            </li>
                            <li>
                <div class="control radio">
                    <input class="" id="Radio3" type="radio" name="Radio_option" value="2">
                    <label class="wrap" for="Radio3" title="">
                        Enter by Branch/Product/Account Number&nbsp;
                    </label>
                </div>
            </li>
            &nbsp;</ul>
    </fieldset>
    <span class="warning"></span>
    <div class="resizeOverlay hidden"></div>
    <div class="sizer vertical" style="position: relative;"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-grip-solid-horizontal"></span></div>
</div>
<div id="Date" class="leaf">
    <label class="control picker" title="Select Date. 
If your parameter supports relative date expressions, you can enter expressions like 'WEEK+1' in this input control">
        <span class="wrap">Select Date</span>
        <input class="date hasDatepicker" type="text" value="~NULL~" id="dp1399014987627">&nbsp;<span class="button picker calTriggerWrapper"><button type="button" class="ui-datepicker-trigger"></button></span>
        <div class="warning"></div>
    </label>
</div>
<div id="Account" class="leaf">
    <label class="control input text" title="">
        <span class="wrap">Select Account Number</span>
        <input class="" type="text" value="[Null]">
        <span class="warning"></span>
    </label>
</div>
<div id="Date1" class="leaf" style="display: none;">
    <label class="control picker" title="Select Date. 
If your parameter supports relative date expressions, you can enter expressions like 'WEEK+1' in this input control">
        <span class="wrap">Select Date</span>
        <input class="date hasDatepicker" type="text" value="~NULL~" id="dp1399014987628">&nbsp;<span class="button picker calTriggerWrapper"><button type="button" class="ui-datepicker-trigger"></button></span>
        <div class="warning"></div>
    </label>
</div>
```

and my validations are written using jQuery in script tag which is as follows:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

jQuery(document).on('change',':radio[name="Radio_option"]',function(event){
    var radiovalue=jQuery(':radio[name="Radio_option"]:checked').val();
        alert(radiovalue);

    if(radiovalue=="~NOTHING~")
    {
        jQuery( "#Date" ).datepicker( "destroy" );
        jQuery( "#Date" ).hide();
        jQuery("#Account").hide();
        jQuery( "#Date1" ).datepicker( "destroy" );
        jQuery("#Date1").hide(); 

    }       

    if(radiovalue =="Enter by Account Number")
    {
        jQuery("#Date").show();
        jQuery("#Account").show();
        jQuery( "#Date1" ).datepicker( "destroy" );
        jQuery("#Date1").hide(); 

        return false;
    }

    if(radiovalue =="2"){
        jQuery( "#Date" ).datepicker( "destroy" );
        jQuery( "#Date" ).hide();
        jQuery("#Account").hide();
        jQuery("#Date1").show();

        return false;
    }

});
});
```

Please suggest me some code where i can hide all fields Date, Account, Date1 when page is loaded.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery("#Date").hide();
    jQuery("#Account").hide();
    jQuery("#Date1").hide(); 
    // other elements to hide 
jQuery(document).on('change',':radio[name="Radio_option"]',function(event){
var radiovalue=jQuery(':radio[name="Radio_option"]:checked').val();
    alert(radiovalue);

if(radiovalue=="~NOTHING~")
{
    jQuery( "#Date" ).datepicker( "destroy" );
    jQuery( "#Date" ).hide();
    jQuery("#Account").hide();
    jQuery( "#Date1" ).datepicker( "destroy" );
    jQuery("#Date1").hide(); 

}       

if(radiovalue =="Enter by Account Number")
{
    jQuery("#Date").show();
    jQuery("#Account").show();
    jQuery( "#Date1" ).datepicker( "destroy" );
    jQuery("#Date1").hide(); 

    return false;
}

if(radiovalue =="2"){
    jQuery( "#Date" ).datepicker( "destroy" );
    jQuery( "#Date" ).hide();
    jQuery("#Account").hide();
    jQuery("#Date1").show();

    return false;
}
```

Alternative

Add style=display:none for divs with Id account and date1

Comment: Dave, if i use in ready function it is not taking those statements. Mean not executed.

Comment: Add style =display:none; for div with Id account and date1. So this will be hidden initially.

Answer (score 1):

On document ready you need to hide the elements.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   jQuery( "#Date" ).hide();
   jQuery( "#Date" ).hide();
   jQuery("#Account").hide();
   jQuery("#Date1").hide();
});
```

EDIT:
[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/66Lpv/)

Comment: I tried this piece of code which you have shared it is not working. It is not identifying JQuery statements. only alert button and condition will work apart from that nothing else.

Comment: This should work. Are you missing something @pallavi , can you add a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is that you may put a class for your input. That way you won't spending too much writing the other input such as textarea.

HTML:

```
<form>
    <input class="form-input-hide" type="text" >
    <textarea class="form-input-hide"></textarea>
</form>
<!-- and so on -->
```

Then hide them.

jQuery:

```
$('.form-input-hide').hide();
```

Comment: where should i write this "$('.form-input').hide();" code. I require it when page is loaded automatically it should get hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Just give them all the same class (in this example `ThingsToHide`, then you can simply hide them with:

HTML:

```
<input class="ThingsToHide" id="Radio2" type="radio" name="Radio_option" value="Enter by Account Number">
```

jQuery:

```
$('.ThingsToHide').hide();
```